# What's the best way to associate a number with a method in x86_64 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, function-pointers

I have a server socket which receives a byte (operation code) from the client.

Depending on what the value of that byte is, I need to decode further data with a specific function.

For example:

- if the value is `0x01`, I need to `call function1` to decode it.
- for `0x02`, execute `call function2`
- and so forth...

I don't want to hardcode it all with compare and jump statements because there are more than 150 possible values and that would result to 400+ lines of code.

What would be the best option to implement this, resulting in the cleanest code? In C language, I would do this with a simple array: `array[index]` where array stores the function pointers and index is the operation code. This would result in O(1) speeds.

This is just a general question, but I'm working with x86_64 asm with NASM syntax if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a table of function pointers is the obvious way in asm as well.
`call [dispatch_table + rax*8]` in non-PIE / non-PIC code where the label address itself [can fit in a 32-bit sign-extended value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) so you can use a label with other registers, otherwise use a RIP-relative LEA to get the table base into another register.  (Look at C compiler output for a function-pointer dispatch if you need an example.)

Don't forget to validate input first, e.g. `cmp eax, MAX_FUNC_NUMBER` / `ja error`, after you do a zero-extending byte load into RAX with `movzx eax, byte [mem]` to zero-extend the index.

Or just a `jmp` instead of call to make it like a switch within a function if that's more convenient than a `call` that pushes a return address.